# Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have:

```
export interface MyObject  {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  timestamp: number | string;
}
```

The timestamp is a number by default but I want to transform it to string in this format 'HH:mm:ss DD/MM/YYYY' using momentjs.

```
const myArray: MyObject[] = [{id: 1, name: 'foo', timestamp: 123},{id: 2, name: 'bar', timestamp: 456}];
```

I am using `.forEach` in order to convert all timestamps to string:

```
myArray.forEach(el => el.timestamp = moment.unix(el.timestamp).format('HH:mm:ss DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

But, I get this error at the `moment.unix` call:

> Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Where did you get this error?

Comment: In `moment.unix(arg)`. The arg should be `number` not a `number | string`

Comment: *is not assignable to parameter of type '**string**'*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moment.unix` only accepts a number as an argument:

https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.d.ts

> ```
> export function unix(timestamp: number): Moment;
> ```

So, make sure that the `timestamp` is a number before passing it to `moment.unix`:

```
myArray.forEach((el) => {
  const { timestamp } = el;
  if (typeof timestamp === 'number') {
    el.timestamp = moment.unix(timestamp).format('HH:mm:ss DD/MM/YYYY')
  } else {
    // will this ever happen? Do whatever you want here - ignore it, or throw
  }
});
```

You could also use *two* object types - one for the numeric timestamp, one for the string format, and use `.map`:

```
export type MyObjectNumTimestamps = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  timestamp: number;
};
export type MyObjectStringTimestamps = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  timestamp: number;
};
```

and initially declare the array as type `MyObjectNumTimestamps`, then turn it into `MyObjectStringTimestamps`:

```
const transformedArray: MyObjectStringTimestamps[] = myArray.map(el => ({
  ...el,
  timestamp: moment.unix(el.timestamp).format('HH:mm:ss DD/MM/YYYY')
}));
```